# Kernel cannot get the option "init" when specifying "root" in QEMU

Tags: linux, kernel, boot

I built the Linux kernel 3.12.8 and busybox-1.22.1, got bzImage and created a rootfs.img with busybox utilities. Then I used QEMU:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -hda ../rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/hda init=/bin/sh"
```

It said that there is no init and told me to pass init to kernel.
If I write "init=/bin/sh root=/dev/hda", it told me that root is (null) and cannot be mounted.
I also tried -append "root=/dev/hda" -append "init=/bin/sh"; the root is also (null).
How can I do to pass init to the kernel?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `init=` directive as long as you place init into a proper folder. `/sbin/init` is a good place for example

Comment: There is /sbin/init linked to busybox already.

Comment: Did you `chmod +x /sbin/init` ?

Comment: Definitely. it is executable.

Comment: I guess you want `root=/dev/hda1` meaning address a partition, not a disk